# Reverse count vector elements when sequence occurs

Tags: r, vector, vectorization, sequence

I have a vector with values `NA`, `0`, and `1`:

```
x <- c(NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA)
#> x
#[1] NA  0  0  1  1  1  1 NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA  1  1  1 NA
```

Whenever the sequence switches from `1` to `NA`, I would like to count the positions of non-`NAs` before that event and replace the elements with that number. I expect this output:

```
#> x_output
#[1] NA  6  5  4  3  2  1 NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA  3  2  1 NA
```

Does anybody have a solution for this? A vectorised approach is preferred because the vectors are long and the dataset is fairly big.

Comment: shouldn't it be `NA  6  5  4  3  2  1 NA 4 3  2  1 NA NA  3  2  1 NA`

Comment: no, I would only like start counting when the sequence switches from `1` to `NA` (see my expected output).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `rle` to define run lengths and `ave` to create the sequences:

```
x <- c(NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, NA)

fun <- function(x) {
  x <- rev(x)
  y <- rle(!is.na(x))
  y$values[y$values] <- seq_along(y$values[y$values])
  y <- inverse.rle(y)

  x[!is.na(x)] <- ave(x[!is.na(x)], y[!is.na(x)], FUN = function(x) {
    if (x[1] == 0L) return(x)
    seq_along(x)
  })
  rev(x)
}

fun(x)
#[1] NA  6  5  4  3  2  1 NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA  3  2  1 NA
```

Comment: Note that if this is a repeated operation and performance is crucial, I'd quickly write a simple loop in Rcpp.

Comment: I think this produces an incorrect output if we change the last element of x to non-NA.

Comment: although not asked explicitly, this side-effect is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Create an 'indx', of TRUE/FALSE column to identify the switching of 1 to NA.  Then, grouped by run-length-id of logical vector (`rleid(is.na(x))`), `if` there are `any` TRUE in 'indx', then get the reverse of sequence of rows or `else` return 'x' and extract the column 'V1'

```
library(data.table)
data.table(x)[, indx := shift(shift(x,  fill = 0) %in% 1 & is.na(x), 
   type = 'lead', fill = FALSE)][, if(any(indx)) rev(seq_len(.N)) else 
             as.integer(x) ,rleid(is.na(x))]$V1
#[1] NA  6  5  4  3  2  1 NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA  3  2  1 NA
```

Comment: what version are you using? I have data.table_1.9.4., maybe the cause of the error? `Error in shift(shift(x, fill = 0) %in% 1 & is.na(x), type = "lead", fill = FALSE) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'shift': Error in shift(x, fill = 0) %in% 1 : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function '%in%': Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shift’ for signature ‘"numeric"’`

Comment: @piptoma It is an old version.  `shift` may be introduced in later versions I am using `data.table_1.10.5`

Comment: unfortunately my company does not allow manual updating of packages, very frustrating....

Answer (score 3):

Another approach

```
library(dplyr)
start_inds <- which(x == 1 & is.na(lead(x)))
na_inds <- which(is.na(x))
sapply(start_inds, function(x) {
   sub_ind = x - na_inds
   end_inds = (x - min(sub_ind[sub_ind > 0]) + 1) : x
   x[end_inds] <<- rev(seq_along(end_inds))
})

x
#[1] NA  6  5  4  3  2  1 NA  0  0  0  0 NA NA  3  2  1 NA
```

We find out the intersection where `x` is equal to 1 and the next element is `NA` using `lead` from `dplyr` which gives us the indices from where we need the change the value backwards. (`start_inds`). We calculate all the indices in the vector where `NA` occurs in `na_inds` so that we can use it to get the closest `NA` value. Now for each of the `start_inds` we subtract it's value with `na_inds` and calculate the closest `NA` value till where we need to change the value (`end_inds`). To select `end_inds` the difference between `start_ind` and `na_inds` has to be greater than 0 as we need to `NA` values which are before `start_ind` and we use `min` to get the recent index of `NA` value. Update the values by generating a sequence `seq_along` using global assignment operator (`<<-`).